# Ant SSH inputing multiple passwords

Tags: bash, ant, ssh, passwords

I am looking for a way to input a password using Ant through an SSH connection.

From what I have read, Ant has SSHExec and SSHSession I can use to open the ssh connection but do not provide a way to input a password for a command run through that ssh connection.

This process is normally done by hand I have built an ant script to automate so far.  Overall what I am trying to do is:

```
ssh user@address
Password:password
someCommand parameter 
Password: [?]
moreCommands
```

Normally I would manually input the password here but I cannot find a way to do it through Ant or Bash.  Is there a way to do this with Ant?

This is my first post in a long time, sorry if I am unclear, ill be online to respond or clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about Ant, but since you asked with reference to Bash, might I suggest using expect?

The below example is built as a function but shows how to accomplish what you want... this assumes you'll be running one command (such as kicking off a remote script) on the SSH command line.

```
exp_comm ()
{
    # Remotely execute an SSH command on another server
    SVR="$1"
    USR="$2"
    PSW="$3"
    TGT="$4"
    ARG="$5"

    /usr/bin/expect <<- EOF 1>>stdout.out 2>>stderr.err
    set timeout 60
    spawn ssh ${USR}@${SVR} '${TGT}' ${ARG}
    expect "*assword:"
    send -- "${PSW}\r"
    expect eof
    EOF
    return $?
}
```

Call it like this:

```
exp_comm "server" "userid" "password" "/tmp/testscript.sh" "'One Big Arg1'"
exp_comm "server" "userid" "password" "/tmp/testscript.sh" "Arg1 Arg2 Arg3"
```

You could modify to run multiple commands, and get into more complex 'smart' commands, by changing the spawn ssh line remove the target script and arguments, and then use expect to do additional things. Something like:

```
/usr/bin/expect <<- EOF 1>>stdout.out 2>>stderr.err
    set timeout 60
    spawn ssh ${USR}@${SVR}
    expect "*assword:"
    send -- "${PASS}\r"
    expect "*>"
    send -- "command1\r"
    expect "*>"
    send -- "command2\r"
    expect eof
    EOF
```

Hope this helps.